# Tailwind css - cover remaining height if there is any else overflow like normal

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am working on a website and on some pages there are very few contents like login page and footer don't reach to bottom, That's why I want main section to cover remaining space if there is any and work like normal if overflow. Basically I want it to work like min-height. I tried using min-height with 100vh and 100% but no desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom min height.

```
<div class="min-h-60">
    content...
</div>
```

In our tailwind config file, you should extend minHeight:

```
module.exports = {
    purge: [],
    theme: {
        extend: {
            minHeight: {
                '60': '15rem'
            }
        }   
    },
    variants: {},
    plugins: []
}
```